# Creating a Total Amount Minus Percentage Forumla

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can someone help me fix this formula so i can get the total? Here is the problem:

```
=sum(K10:K29)-M15
```

So basically, Im looking for  Cells K10:K29 total displayed on L3 Minus M15 which M15 is the user % input. So like in math it would look like $1,230- 14% = ‭$1,057.8‬. Please and thank you, Im working on a project that needs that formula to work.

Comment: are your numbers formatted as numbers? if not you might use another function. can you tell what are the contents in `K10:K29` and in `M15`?

Comment: I believe so, you can view it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/14bJxv-7uzbEvxojEB0FAXcyBYflPiF29/view?usp=sharing If and when you view it, the total is suppose to go into cell L3 as teh mathematical answer to that is suppose to be $31.05

Comment: However.....its not showing that answer in the L3 cell, it shows some other bogus number

Comment: I think you'll need to revisit your math. 14% is equal to 0.14 so the equation $1,230-14%=1,230-0.14=1,229.86. You'll need to multiply the 14% with the sum to find the 14% of the total to then deduct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula in L3 should be:

> `=K9*(1-M15)`

Because that way you are actually substracting between percentages (100%-User%).

Comment: OMG @Aerials, thank you thank you so much. That actually fixed the problem and the answer is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is the remainder of the percentage (in your example 100%-14%=86%) so the formula to use is `=sum(K10:K29)*(1-M15)`.

Your problem is in the math part. The percent is just that, a ratio. You need to multiply the ratio with the amount to reach the value you're after, e.g. 14% equals the value 0.14. However, multiplying it with 1,230 gives you 14% of 1,230 (172.2) which is presumably what you want to deduct.

I think this must be due to many calculators allowing for exactly the shortcut you're trying to do despite being mathematically dubious. This to make calculations simpler in shops.